# Paddle switch Pass and Seymor model RCD38

Tags: electrical

I have the following model paddle switch/receptacle  Pass and Seymor  Legrand Radiant Model RCD38
Can I configure this switch paddle/receptacle  so that the switch controls the outlet only ?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing easier.  Attach 2 wires (+ground).

- Attach the neutral wire to the silver screw on the receptacle side.
- Attach the always-hot wire to one of the brass (traveler) screws on the 3-way switch side.
- Don't break off the tab.

If you don't like which throw is "on", move the always-hot wire to the other traveler screw.

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick response  I will give it a try.

Comment: that's it worked like a charm thanks again for your help .